# DNS Settings for www.domain.com and non-www domain.com

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting

I have just put a new website up onto a new hosting package and am (possibly) having problems with the DNS settings.  I say possibly it may just be a propagation issue as it's only just changed.

Client have website and email on their own server.  They have taken out a new hosting package just for their website (email remains as is on there own server)

I have DNS settings for:

@
exchange
remote
webmail
www

I changed www to point to the new IP for the hosting and www.domain.com works instantly.

Non-www is still pointing at the old site, do I need to change the @ entry, add a * entry or something else.  I wasn't able to add a blank entry.

Key thing is that email continues to be routed via the original IP address to their own server.

Following the comment below, domains are: squeezedmedia.com and www.squeezedmedia.com

Comment: If you put the real domain information here, it would be easy for others to look at the actual config.  Anything less, we're shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, the cache servers had the old entry, not the new one. 
From my cache server, I see no problem:
www.squeezedmedia.com.  86400   IN      A       195.26.90.15
squeezedmedia.com.      86345   IN      A       195.26.90.15

TTL is important and you should change it to a low value when you plan to change hosting providers.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know.  I did change the @ A record as well but the MX record is still pointing to the exchange server